# Saves file fine when it's small/blank, but says access denied when larger

Tags: c#

I'm scraping data, then saving the details into an HTML document. To put it into perspective, the maximum amount of rows within the HTML table is 200.

While running test, the following works:

```
string fileDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy");
string dayofweek = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).DayOfWeek.ToString();
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"" + fileDate + ".html", "hi"); // blank doc with "hi" in it.
```

However, using the data I scrape, which is populated with my `content` string, which can be seen here:

```
string fileDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy");
string dayofweek = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).DayOfWeek.ToString();
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"" + fileDate + ".html", content);
```

It spits out an error, which is the following

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\Friday, 18 June 2021.html' is denied.
> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
> at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
> at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
> at System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile(String path, Boolean append, Boolean checkHost)
> at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
> at System.IO.File.InternalWriteAllText(String path, String contents, Encoding encoding, Boolean checkHost)
> at System.IO.File.WriteAllText(String path, String contents)
> at carValLocal.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Gamer\source\repos\carValLocal\carValLocal\Program.cs:line 512

I do not understand how the content within the HTML document can alter if I'm authorized to write the file. It makes no sense, does anybody know how to fix this?

Please note, this is using a console application in C#.

Comment: 1) What's the point of `@""`? 2) Why are you saving to the System32 folder? Are you sure you have the right permissions (and a good reason) to do so? 3) What is the actual path that you're using in your code?

Comment: 1. Possibly just bad coding, I'm fairly new to C#.  2. I just go that so it lands in my debug folder. Now, although this is useful information to know that it's probably not a good idea, it wouldn't explain why a blank HTML doc saves, but one with content doesn't, surely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason is not the file content. It's how you start your program.
In your code you store html file content at working directory and your program starts from C:\Windows\System32 and when it wants to create a new file it gets error.

For testing that you can store your file in some absolute directory you have write permission or change your working directory.

For use absolute directory use can try something like this

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\" + fileDate + ".html", content);
```